# Android many alternatives for relative position / stack

Tags: android, layout

I have to position view A on top of view B and B on top of view C.

Has to behave like a stack on visibility change (gone) or element removal. If I remove B, A has to be on top of C, if I remove C, B goes to the bottom of the parent and A keeps above B, if I remove B and C, A goes to the bottom of the parent.

[image]

Currently I have this attributes:

C:

```
android:id="@+id/C"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

B:

```
android:id="@+id/B"
android:layout_above="@id/C"
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
```

A:

```
android:layout_above="@id/B"
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
```

But I need something like "if there's B, align above it, if not, align on top of C, if not align the bottom of the parent".

Is there a way to solve this in XML wihout nested layouts?

Comment: Not completly, see my last comment at RorolePro's answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, instead of using RelativeLayout, is to use a LinearLayout with a fourth view with a layout_weight set to 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/C"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: instead of the forth view, you can put your linearlayout in a relativelayout with alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: @njzk2: Agreed. Same as the answer above, but remove the "Spacer" view, make the Linear layout alignParentBottom="true" and set the layout_height of the LinearLayout to WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: For better performance, it's better to increase the hierarchy view horizontally than vertically, that's why I propose this solution, but, your solution works too.

Comment: This is a way to solve it. But right now I have a case where I guess it's not usable. I have to use a relative layout, because I want to put the bottom-items in FRONT of everything else in the screen. I can't push them down like you say using a 4th layout above because it would hide/consume the events from my actual layout behind.